404 Not Found - nginx/1.24.0 Error for PHP CodeIgniter3 in Azure App Service
I'm running a PHP CodeIgniter application on an Azure App Service, and it has been working perfectly until recently. Now, I'm encountering a 404 Not Found - nginx/1.24.0 error.
Here's a bit more detail:
Platform: Azure App Service
Web Server: nginx/1.24.0
Framework: PHP CodeIgniter

Checked the application logs: No specific errors related to the 404 issue.
Verified the deployment: All files seem to be in place, and no changes were made recently.
Checked nginx configuration: No changes, and it appears to be correctly configured.
Restarted the service: Tried restarting the Azure App Service but the issue persists.
Azure diagnostics: No unusual resource usage or errors reported.


Inorder for the PHP app to load properly make sure the startup command is present as the nginx container uses this path by default - _/etc/nginx/sites-available/default_ Thus its necessary to erase this file during app restart:-
Startup command:-
cp /home/site/wwwroot/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default && service nginx reload


Also, Copy the nginx default file to home/site/default folder Reference my SO Answer for the app to load properly.

Reference2 taken from MS Document.


Also, Retry your Deployment via github actions or Azure Devops pipeline for the app to get deployed correctly:-
Github Actions:-

Output:-

